# Cannot receive and store value of the specific data from Firebase DB - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue with retrieving and storing single data from FirebaseDatabase. During the debugging on my watch list i get value of the snapshot as null. I need to get **city** name of the current user from db.

```
  void addToFb() async {
    final User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;
    final city = await FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child('Users')
      .equalTo(uid)
      .once()
      .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        var temp = snapshot.value.city;
        return temp;
      });
```

Just in case my database looks like this:

```
 - Users
 |- uid
 ||- name
 ...
 ||- city
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the solution but for make your code and db structure easy,

I suggest you to use [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview/)

Because you can find all types of queries in this.

[Cloud Firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) dependency

Comment: Thanks i followed your advice and turned into FirebaseFirestore, it worked out +Karma @priyesh