# how to check email already exist in multiple table in firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

how I can write:

```
 if (email and password that be entered exist in **User** table in realtime  firebase){}
 else if (email and password that be entered exist in **UserPart** table in realtime firebase){} 
 else if (email and password that be entered exist in **UserSpon** table in firebase){}
 else {show "there is no account related to this enter information}
```

**in flutter app**

Comment: I will suggest you to use firebase cloud (firestore). https://stackoverflow.com/a/66169707/13961240

Comment: can i write this code with realtime firebase ?

Comment: I dont have much know in realtime because they will provide very limited query structure. We can not create complex queries. Sorry for it.

Comment: If you're asking if you can perform a query against the Realtime Database, the answer is yes. You can query all of the nodes outlined in your question. What have you tried?